# heap buffer overflow in c

Tags: c, malloc, overflow

So i wrote this program, but get a lot of messages saying heap buffer overflow problem. However i can"t see the problem, can anyone help please.
Here is the code, overflow happens when i type in g (any integer) (any integer)

```
char **ptr;
void setmine();

/* create a minefield
**/
void setmine(int width , int height) {
    ptr = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char)*height);

    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        ptr[i] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*width);
    }

}


int main(void) {
    char line1[20];
    char command1;
    int width, height; 
    fgets(line1,20,stdin);
    sscanf(line1,"%c %d %d",&command1, &width, &height);

    if(command1=='g'){
        setmine(width, height);
    }

    else{
        printf("error");
        exit(0);
    }


    char line2[20];
    char command2;
    int column, row;
    fgets(line2,20,stdin);
    sscanf("%c %d %d", &command2, &column, &row);
    if(command2=='g'){
        printf("error");
        exit(0);
    }
    else if(command2=='b'){
        setbomb(column,row);
    }
    else if(command2=='u'){
        uncover(column,row, width, height);
    }
    else if(command2=='f'){
        flag(column,row);
    }

}
```

Comment: How doesw code know `sscanf("%c %d %d", &command2, &column, &row);` succeeded before using `command2, column, row` without checking the result of `sscanf()`?

Comment: first one should be `sizeof (char*)` or even better `sizeof (*ptr)`

Comment: and the problem of not checking the `sscanf` return value; if input was invalid, the `width`, `height` would now contain garbage and probably exhaust your virtual memory on 32-bit systems and whatnot.

Comment: I would expect `ptr = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char)*height);` to be `ptr = malloc(sizeof *ptr  *height);`  (pointer size vs char size).

Answer (score 2):

Let me help you a bit on this. I fixed some of your mistakes in the code, putting also comments behind.

```
char **ptr;
// void setmine(); // Parameter were missing here. You don't that anyways, because you defined setmine(int width , int height) before main

/* create a minefield
**/
void setmine(int width , int height) {
    ptr = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char*)*height); // Size of pointer to char must be used.

    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) { // Now this should work
        ptr[i] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*width);
    }

}


int main(void) {
    char line1[20];  
    char command1;
    int width, height; 
    fgets(line1,20,stdin);
    sscanf(line1,"%c %d %d",&command1, &width, &height);

    if(command1=='g'){
        setmine(width, height);
    }

    else{
        printf("error");
        exit(0);
    }


    char line2[20];
    char command2;
    int column, row;
    fgets(line2,20,stdin);
    sscanf(line2, "%c %d %d", &command2, &column, &row); // Missing line2
    if(command2=='g'){
        printf("error");
        exit(0);
    }
    else if(command2=='b'){
        setbomb(column,row); // No idea how this is called
    }
    else if(command2=='u'){
        uncover(column,row, width, height); // No idea how this is called
    }
    else if(command2=='f'){
        flag(column,row); // No idea how this is called
    }

}
```

Don't get me wrong, but I think you should practice a bit more. Does it have to be C? I also see your attempts with mallocs. I think C++ is a bit easier thanks to the memory management templates it brings in STL. Let me know...

Comment: I am just getting started in c, i am doing my assignment so it has to be in c.  I didn't put all my functions here, sorry for the confusion. Thanks a lot by the way and do you know any good ways of practicing C?

Comment: Hehe, for assignment I guess it is okay, but if you really want to learn it, try to create a simple video game like Tetris. It requires a lot of practice, but that practice will make you strong.